# Connecting picturebox with listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox, picturebox

I'm using vb.net form

I have a listbox (listbox1 ) and a picturebox (picturebox1) and a button1

listbox1 contains alot of items 
and picturebox1 contains the same number of items with same name

i'm trying to make the picturebox1 display the image that i select from the listbox1 item ( by clicking on the button1 )

I tried this code but image did'nt appear

```
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Me.ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear (= impossible for us to know what is going wrong), but you should be able to quickly fix the problem after some debugging; what means that this is off-topic here. In the future, please try to make sure that you provide all the required information and ask questions which are relevant for others. PS: your problem is most likely provoked because `Me.ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()` doesn't contain a valid path to an image (perhaps you are including just the file name, perhaps you don't have access to the given location, perhaps no item is selected, etc.).

Comment: What type of items are there in Listbox1?

Comment: @varocarbas the question is very clear

Comment: ?! Not it is not. I have explained you the reasons, what part don't you understand in my comment above. I will put it a still simpler example by asking you something: what is the colour of the pullover I am currently wearing? My question is clear isn't it? Please, answer it.

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ items in the listbox is string and images name in the picturebox is identical to the listbox items

Comment: @varocarbas I see a reddish sort of thing.

Comment: @bod Do you add the extensions?

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ Ey!! Don't help the OP! LOL. Not even close (it is blue). Basically what the question of the OP will deliver: blind guesses for as long as he will not be providing the required information. That's why the question is not clear (better: the required information is not provided) and is offtopic. Even in case of being extremely clear it would be off-topic.

Comment: ex. listbox item is "15" and image in the picturebox is "15"

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ should i add "jpg" extension to the listbox item?

Comment: Are the images in your directory? You will need to add the extensions accordingly.

Comment: I uploaded the image by manual importing to the picturebox

Comment: what? picturebox is not dropbox. .. I mean how did you do so?

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ You shouldn't promote off-topic behaviours. This question is off-topic at all the levels (= unclear, not useful to anyone and easily fixed after a simple debugging) and you are not even helping the OP learn.

Comment: i clicked on the choose image in the picturebox and import the images

Answer (score 1):

You can add an ImageList control to store your images. The listbox and the picturebox controls can access them through their properties. Below is the code that works very similar to what you want.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Each imagesNames As String In ImageList1.Images.Keys
            ListBox1.Items.Add(imagesNames)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images.Item(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
    End Sub
```

When you click a listbox item it will show its corresponding picture.

You have to change the property ColorDepth in the imagelist and sizemode in the picturebox to look better.